# Change a string of frozen set to frozen set

Tags: python, frozenset

I came across with this `"frozenset({' ABC'})"` in pandas dataframe but I would like to change it from object type back to frozenset type , for example like this `frozenset({' ABC'})` in the row.

Comment: Please provide a short code example, it seems likely that this is a classic mistake of confusing the representation of a value with the actual value.

Comment: Perhaps `ast.literal_eval()`, although it sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Why do you have that in your dataframe in the first place? It sounds like this is a problem that should be fixed by fixing the code that creates the problem, rather than trying to post-process the result.

Comment: *"change it from object type back to frozenset type"* -- Pandas doesn't have a `frozenset` type... It'd go under `object`.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. For reference on what j1's saying: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.